# bokeh tools of PreviewSavetool and BoxSelectionOverlay import error

Tags: python, bokeh

I got some examples of application web mapping using python and bokeh and got error for `previewsavetool` and `BoxSelectionOverlay`. It said cannot import the library. I use bokeh version 0.12.6. Could anyone help me what the new tool for `PreviewSaveTool` and `BoxSelectionOverlay` in bokeh 0.12.6 version?

Here is the code:

```
from bokeh.models import (
    GMapPlot, Range1d, ColumnDataSource, LinearAxis,
    HoverTool, PanTool, WheelZoomTool, BoxSelectTool, ResetTool, 
    PreviewSaveTool, BoxSelectionOverlay,
    GMapOptions, NumeralTickFormatter, PrintfTickFormatter)
```

Comment: This question should be re-opened. It contains the shortest code necessary to produce and problem (including version information), and states the problem explicitly in the title (an import error). Anyone can infer the desired behavior, namely "not an import error".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the `BoxSelectionOverlay` and the `PreviewSavetool` are depreciated as of Bokeh 0.12.6. `BoxSelectionOverlay` was last available in version 0.10.0 and `PreviewSavetool` in version 0.11.0

You can choose to revert to a previous version or simply use the new models. `PreviewSavetool` is now `SaveTool` and the functionality of `BoxSelectionOverlay` has been integrated in `BoxSelectTool`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried and it worked.